# Java Mail to Read The Mail

Tags: java, swing, email, client

I'm getting this error when tried to read mail using JavaMail. Please let me know how to resolve this error :

Part of my code :

```
referhEmail();
    }

    private void referhEmail(){
         try {
        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");      
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "110");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.host", "localhost");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props); 
        final Store store = session.getStore("pop3");  
        store.connect("localhost","xxxx@localhost", "xxx");
```

And the error :

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Username or password is invalid or incorrect.
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:213)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at emailclientgamal.EmailClientGamal.referhEmail(EmailClientGamal.java:462)
at emailclientgamal.EmailClientGamal.connect(EmailClientGamal.java:449)
at emailclientgamal.EmailClientGamal.main(EmailClientGamal.java:551)
```

Comment: Is your username or password invalid or incorrect?

Comment: @AndyTurner There is nothing wrong, it just seems like it fails authentication, i've tried for the other way but still can not. I used mercury for server.